# Carriage Return is making trouble

Tags: string, carriage-return

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
char name[25];
printf("Enter Your Full Name:");
int i = 0;
name[i] = getche(); 

while(name[i] != '\r')
{
    i++;
    name[i] = getche();
}
printf("\n%s\n", name);
system("pause");
}
```

On execution when I enter name Razwan Muzaffar I am getting the wrong output. While with some other names the output is Ok. But when I try some other names, makes trouble. Carriage return or buffer memory flush, I think something like is a point of consideration. 
I am absolute beginner. So kindly explain the issue.

[image]

Comment: Did you used backspace while typing the name?

Comment: No. I attempted more times. But got the same issue. Anyhow, issue is solved already. After loop name[i] = '\0';